# Issue with AJAX Request Preview in Chrome DevTools Version 123.0.6312.59

Tags: ajax, symfony, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

Following the recent update to Google Chrome version 123.0.6312.59 (Official Build) (64-bit), I've been experiencing an issue with the display of AJAX responses in the developer tools (DevTools). Before this update, encoded responses were properly interpreted and displayed in a readable format. However, now, I see the encoded content (e.g., %3Cscript%3E%20Sfdump...) in the AJAX response preview without it being decoded into HTML.

Here is an example of what I'm seeing in the AJAX response preview:

```
%3Cscript%3E%20Sfdump%20%3D%20window.Sfdump%20%7C%7C%20(function(doc)%20...
```

This behavior occurs when viewing a Symfony dump, but I suspect it could affect other similarly encoded content. The same script works correctly on Firefox, where the encoded content is decoded and displayed as expected.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or do you have suggestions on how to force Chrome to correctly interpret these encoded responses in DevTools?

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

I've tried clearing the cache and restarting the browser, but the issue persists. I couldn't find an option in DevTools to control this feature.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a chrome bug. Fixed in latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac with 123.0.6312.59 and just fixed it by updating to 123.0.6312.87 (Official Build) (arm64). Go to `chrome://settings/help` and check for updates